# Add Images from a URL using JSON

Tags: java, android, json, api, url

I am new to JSON. I would be thankful to you for helping me. How to add parse in image via Json. Can someone tell me what am I missing here? I want image of each news link to be displayed on my `ImageView` ( a placeholder in xml) here is the link and api.
 https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=6a6f7c77766442acb20c86157a152131"

Thank you so much for helping

---

Here is my code in Query.Java

```
try {
    JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(bookJson);
    JSONArray newsArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("articles");

    for (int i = 0; i < newsArray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject currentNews = newsArray.getJSONObject(i);
        /*JSONObject properties = currentNews.getJSONObject("articles");*/
        JSONObject newsSource = currentNews.getJSONObject("source");

        String title = currentNews.getString("title");
        String description = currentNews.getString("description");
        String url = currentNews.getString("url");
        /*String name = properties.getString("name");*/
        String name = newsSource.getString("name");
        String time = currentNews.getString("publishedAt");

        String image = currentNews.getString("urlToImage");



        News news = new News (title, description, url, name, time, image);
```

here is the code in custom class

```
package com.example.trynews;

public class News {

    private String mTitle;
    private String mDescription;
    private String mUrl;
    private String mSource;
    private String mTime;
    private String mUrlImage;




    public News (String title, String description, String url, String name, String time, String images) {
        mTitle = title;
        mDescription = description;
        mUrl = url;
        mSource = name;
        mTime = time;
        mUrlImage = images;
 }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return mDescription;
    }

    public String getURL() {
        return mUrl;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return mSource;
    }
    public String getTIME() {
        return mTime;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return mUrlImage;
    }


}
```

and here is the code in adapter (listview)

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {
    public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<News> newss) {
        super(context, 0, newss);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.news_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        News currentNews = getItem(position);


        TextView titleView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleView.setText(currentNews.getTitle());


        TextView descripView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        descripView.setText(currentNews.getDescription());




        TextView sourceView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.newsSource);
        sourceView.setText(currentNews.getName());


        TextView timeView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        timeView.setText(currentNews.getTIME());



        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImagerResource(currentNews.getImageUrl());

        I am getting an error here it says I cant add a String inside setImageResource. 



        return listItemView;
    }
```

Comment: show your api response. json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show image from url, easy way is using image library.

for example `Glide`

add build.gradle

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
}
```

and in your adapter,

```
imageView.setImagerResource(currentNews.getImageUrl());
```

change to

```
Glide.with(getContext).load(currentNews.getImageUrl()).into(imageView);
```

Or use bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap; // this is global 




Thread mthread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(currentNews.getImageUrl());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

mthread.start();

try {
    mthread.join();
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it works like a charm very thankful to you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
   URL url = new URL(currentNews.getImageUrl());
   Bitmap bitmap = 
   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
   imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Try above code

Answer (score 0):

Use picasso library for loading image from URL : Here is a link you must follow for that if you like : https://medium.com/@prakash_pun/retrofit-a-simple-android-tutorial-48437e4e5a23